# dynamic button wont trigger event on other elements even with .on used datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a button in a row in datatables that when clicked, fires a function that at the end should trigger a form to submit. I am using `$(document).on('click', '.row-button', function(){ ... })` I test it with `console.log('clicked')` and it logs for every click. But when I try to trigger the form to submit with `$('#form_to_send'). trigger('submit')`that is completely ignored and never fires.

If I take datatables of everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
 itemTable = $('table#itemTable').DataTable({
      "aaSorting": [],
      columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      targets: [0,1,10],
      "scrollY": "10vh",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "scrollX": true
      }]
    });
    $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select'); code here

 
 

  
    $(document).on('click', '.item-task', function(){
   //get the route      
  page = $(this).attr('data-href');
  
  //get the title of the action
  title = $(this).attr('data-title');
 
  //get the specific task
  func =  $(this).attr('data-func');

  //set the title of the modal
  modalTitle.innerText = title     
  $('#itemform').trigger("submit");
  });
```

Comment: have you tried to console the onsubmit event of your form , this hsould trigger !

Comment: @SadhilSpring I'm not sure I know exactly how to do that. But I used the step-through debugger in chrome to watch the form submit. For elements on the first page every thing works. Elements on paginated pages don't. The event is captured but the form never submits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a typo in another part of my code. That is indeed the correct syntax. Thank you @SadhilSpring for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  itemTable = $('table#itemTable').DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [],
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      "scrollY": "10vh",
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      "scrollX": true
    }]
  });
  //$('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');

  $('.item-task').on("click",function(){
    console.log("hhhhh");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.item-task', function() {
    //get the route      
    page = $(this).attr('data-href');

    //get the title of the action
    //title = $(this).attr('data-title');

    //get the specific task
    //func = $(this).attr('data-func');

    //set the title of the modal
    //modalTitle.innerText = title
    
    console.log(page);
    $('#itemform').trigger("submit");
  });
  
  $("#itemform").on("submit",function(e){
    alert("form submitetd")
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="itemTable" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th> acion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
      <td><button class="item-task" data-href="#hello">click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
      <td><button class="item-task" data-href="#world">click</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<form id="itemform" >
  <input type="text" value="test" />
</form>
```